# OpenVPN clients cannot share their connection to the Internet

Tags: dns, vpn, openvpn, dhcp, router

> Context: a Wifi VPN gateway (Linux Ubuntu computer)
>
> - Simply One distant Server (www.example.com) and One Client (Paul, Ubuntu Linux, gateway) *linked* with  `openVpn`. Server allows Paul to browse the Internet
> - Paul Client wants to share its connexion (via Wifi AP) to Jack & Sophie.

**Problem:** Jack & Sophie can only browser the Server homepage (www.example.com). Any other request (IP, ping, nslookup...) fails (NO_INTERNET) if it doesn't concern Server domainname.com or IP. However Paul can browse anything he wants.

NB: **Ip forwarding is 1/enabled**. Accessing the Internet without VPN works 100%.

How can I fix it ?

---

Server `IPTABLES` IF USEFUL

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1623:213921]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [911:146048]
:acctboth - [0:0]
:cphulk - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j cphulk 
-A INPUT -j acctboth 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun+ -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -j acctboth 
-A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT 
-A acctboth -s 3.1.170.110/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 3.1.170.110/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 3.1.170.110/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 3.1.170.110/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 3.1.170.110/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 3.1.170.110/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 3.1.170.110/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 3.1.170.110/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 3.1.170.110/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 3.1.170.110/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 3.1.170.110/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 3.1.170.110/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 3.1.170.110/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -d 3.1.170.110/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -s 10.8.0.1/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 10.8.0.1/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 10.8.0.1/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 10.8.0.1/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 10.8.0.1/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 10.8.0.1/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 10.8.0.1/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 10.8.0.1/32 ! -i lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 10.8.0.1/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 10.8.0.1/32 ! -i lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 10.8.0.1/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 10.8.0.1/32 ! -i lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 10.8.0.1/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth -d 10.8.0.1/32 ! -i lo 
-A acctboth ! -i lo 
-A cphulk -s 22.16.21.100/32 -m state --state NEW -m time --datestop 2015-09-16T18:53:55 --utc -j DROP 
-A cphulk -s 0.0.0.0/32 -m state --state NEW -m time --datestop 2015-09-17T00:34:27 --utc -j DROP 
-A cphulk -s 4.68.02.109/32 -m state --state NEW -m time --datestop 2015-09-17T01:44:56 --utc -j DROP 
-A cphulk -s 9.1.218.145/32 -m state --state NEW -m time --datestop 2015-09-17T04:03:24 --utc -j DROP 
-A cphulk -s 3.1.4.79/32 -m state --state NEW -m time --datestop 2015-09-17T11:21:00 --utc -j DROP 
COMMIT
```

____ ROUTE when VPN is **on** :

```
Destination     Passerelle      Genmask         Indic Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.8.0.77       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.77       255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.77       *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
13.37.42.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
ns350510.ip-37- 192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.77       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

___ ROUTE when VPN is **off**

```
Destination     Passerelle      Genmask         Indic Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
13.37.42.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to enable forwarding:

```
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding
```

Also, your tunneled IPs (here 10.0.0.0/8) are likely to be private, so do NAT/MASQUERADING:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: thank you but forwarding is 1 for a while.

Comment: What about the routing table on the client side. It should show a route to your vpn host and a default route via the the VPN server's private IP. DNS should point to a server on the VPN server side as well.

Comment: Yes, I edit for routes.               =========== it seems the right way. I started by putting "route-nopull" in thee vpn client config'. Then I ll make route (maybe executed at the end of connection, thanks to "up" option in client config'). ... Yes too for DNS, but I use 8888/8884 Google DNS, there is no need to point anywhere, just having wlan & tun0 connected. That's the whole thing: without VPN, the forwarding is **wlan<=>eth** . Once vpn is ON, **wlan<=>tun** . This is a route example ?